# Yammer authentication popup even with O365 federated

Tags: azure-active-directory, sitecore, office365, yammer

Integrating Sitecore with Yammer.
Unable to get around the Yammer authentication popup even after enforcing the same office 365 identity as indicated in the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/yammer/configure-your-yammer-network/enforce-office-365-identity

can the popup be bypassed?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the desktop notifier? If you are using this and are getting the popup after logging on to the computer you can navigate to the yammer notifier app, click on "settings", and uncheck the option Launch Yammer Notifier on start-up. Then click "save."

[image]

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/yammer/manage-yammer-users/auto-acceleration-policy-for-signing-in